# How to iterate over multiple lists simultaneously

Tags: python

I have a list of lists (the amount of lists which is created each time the code runs is passed in as an argument), and in each list I need to iterate over the items of each of the second lists in the x amount of lists.

The simplified format would be:

```
list = [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]], [[1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12]]]
```

And I need to iterate through the list doing (4 + 7 + 10), (5 + 8 + 11) and (6 + 9 + 12).

I haven't made much progress in coding this, at the moment I am just adding together the items in each of the second lists:

```
mean_list = []
for i in list1:
    each_item = 0
    for ca in i[1]:
        each_item += ca
    mean_list.append(each_item)
print(mean_list)
```

The end result should be `mean_list = [21, 24, 27]` using the example above.

Comment: What is the point of the [1, 2, 3] sub-lists?

Comment: The code returns two things, I then put both of these into a new list; the code doesn't work if I remove the first lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). The first [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) is to select the second lists within each sublist and the second is to interleave the elements from these in order to simply take the `sum` and the `mean`:

```
from statistics import mean
sums, means = zip(*[(sum(i), mean(i)) for i in zip(*list(zip(*l))[1])])

print(sums)
# (21, 24, 27)
print(means)
# (7, 8, 9)
```

Comment: I actually forgot to mention that I would need to find the mean for each thing (so in this case it would be [7, 8, 9]

Comment: the mean for each thing? where do the `[7, 8, 9]` come from? @JonathanDyke

Comment: There are three items being added together in this case, so [7, 8, 9] would be [21/3, 24/3, 28/3], and I've not used zip before so I'm not sure where you retrieve the amount of items being summed (just doing /3 wouldn't work because the actual number of lists changes)

Answer (score 0):

I dont't know what is the exact purpose but hardcodedly we can do this....

```
l = [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]], [[1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12]]]
mean_list = []
for i in range(len(l[0][0])):
    mysum = 0
    for j in l:
        mysum+=j[1][i]
    mean_list.append(mysum)
print(mean_list)
```

Outputs
`[21, 24, 27]`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a tensor. You can use `numpy` for matrix addition, it will be much faster than any manual job.

```
import numpy as np

mat = np.array([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]], [[1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12]]])

print(mat.mean(axis=0)[1]) # [7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: or `mat.sum(axis=0)[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Some comprehension, sum and zip magic:

```
>>> i = [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]], [[1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12]]]
>>> q = [x[1] for x in i]
>>> [sum(i) for i in zip(*q)]
[21, 24, 27]
```

To get the mean, divide by the length:

```
>>> [sum(i)/len(i) for i in zip(*q)]
[7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with numpy sum.

```
import numpy as np

list1 = [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]], [[1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12]]]

result = np.array(list1).sum(axis = 0)[1]
print(result)
#array([21, 24, 27])
```

EDIT: For Mean, as OP apparently wanted instead, just change the sum operation to mean.

```
result_mean = np.array(list1).mean(axis = 0)[1]
#array([7., 8., 9.])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a double `zip` in the list comprehension:

```
l = [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]], [[1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12]]]

[sum(j) for num, i in enumerate(zip(*l)) 
        for j in zip(*i) if num % 2]
# [21, 24, 27]
```

If you need the mean use `statistics.mean()` instead of `sum`.